# Python: Storing Values in __return__ System Variable?

Tags: python

I was given a task to do in python, and have to "store an expression to the system variable `__return__`", then later return the value of `__return__` in another function.

I understand what `__return__` is, however, I am not sure of how one would "store" something to it for later use?

Should I ask for further clarification on the topic, or is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear to me, if we are talking about '\_\_return__' for pdb debugging or some environment variable called '\_\_return__' :)

Comment: It was labeled a "system variable", and I don't think it has anything to do with the pdb debugger.

Comment: Then the answer from @Tal should be satisfying :)

Answer (score 2):

A system variable is a global variable that is accessible anywhere from your system.

In Windows, for example, you can see your system variables by pressing Winkey and then searching for *Edit the system environment variables*, and then clicking on the *environment variables...* button.
(Note: In Windows you can have separate variables for user and for the whole system).

In Linux, `printenv` in a terminal will print your environment variables.

Back to Python:
You can store said expression to the relevant system variable by using

```
import os
os.environ['__return__'] = some_expression
```

And get the expression back by using

```
def foo():
    return os.environ['__return__']
```